# Sorting array of chars alphabetically then by length

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, data-structures, char

I have an array of structs where I keep track of how many times each unique word was seen in a given text:

```
struct List {
  char word[20];
  int repeat;
};
```

Now I need to sort this:

```
as             6
a              1
appetite       1
angry          1
are            2
and            4
...
```

To this:

```
a            1
as           6
and          4
are          2
angry        1
appetite     1
...
```

(By alphabetically I mean only by first letter)
So far, I have come up with this:

```
for (i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
        min_pos = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) // find min
            if (array[j].word[0] < array[min_pos].word[0]) {
                min_pos = j;
            }
            swap = array[min_pos]; // swap
            array[min_pos] = array[i];
            array[i] = swap;
        }
```

This code works perfectly for sorting alphabetically, but I just can't write proper code to sort BOTH alphabetically and by length.

Comment: This would be easier by using `std::string`.  You could use `std::map<std::string, int>` to associate words with frequencies.  The sorting would be handled for you.  Natural sorting of `std::string` is by letter, then length, e.g. `"aa" before "ba".

Comment: It's unclear here what the purpose of `swap_pos` is. Is it supposed to be `min_pos`?

Comment: Yes, forgot to change it back.

Comment: The second ```for``` - where is it's opening brace? The first ```for``` where is it's closing brace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have pointed out that there are faster and cleaner ways to sort. But if you want to use your own selection sort, as you've written, then you just need to make a few changes to your code.

Separate the "do I need to swap" logic from the swapping logic itself. Then the code becomes much cleaner and it's more clear where to add the extra check.

I've only copied the inner loop here. You'd want to replace your existing inner loop with this one. I'm not clear on why you need `swap_pos` and `min_pos`, so I've left the semantics alone.

```
    for (j = i + 1; j < length; j++) { // find min
        // first, determine whether you need to swap
        // You want to swap if the first character of the new word is
        // smaller, or if the letters are equal and the length is smaller.
        bool doSwap = false;
        if (array[j].word[0] < array[min_pos].word[0]) {
            doSwap = true;
        }
        else if (array[j].word[0] == array[min_pos].word[0] &&
                 strlen(array[j].word) < array[min_pos].word) {
            doSwap = true;
        }

        // do the swap if necessary
        if (doSwap) {
            swap_pos = j;
            swap = array[min_pos]; // swap
            array[min_pos] = array[i];
            array[i] = swap;
        }
    }
```

To more clearly illustrate the necessary logic changes, I've purposely avoided making major style changes or simple optimizations.

Comment: Ended up putting your loop in `do ... while (doSwap)`
Works like a charm, thank you.

Comment: @enjoy I don't think that conditional loop is a good idea with selection sort. The general case of selection sort doesn't allow for an early out.

Answer (score 6):

**Make a comparator function**.

Add an `operator<` to your `List`:

```
bool operator<(const List &lhs) const {
    if(word[0] != lhs.word[0]) {
        return word[0] < lhs.word[0];
    }
    return strlen(word) < strlen(lhs.word);
}
```

And now use this operator to sort, using whichever algorithm strikes your fancy.

Comment: Great idea. I would combine it with my idea to: Use tuple lexicographical compare operators. (answer below)

Answer (score 1):

**Use tuple lexicographical compare operators**

An easy way to not write this condition is to

```
#include <tuple>
```

Then [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) can be used:

```
std::tie(array[j].word[0], array[j].repeat) < std::tie(array[min_pos].word[0], array[min_pos].repeat)
```

This works because [`std::tie`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tie) creates a tuple of lvalue references to its arguments. (Which means `std::tie` requires variables. If You want to compare results from functions [`std::make_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple) or [`std::forward_as_tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/forward_as_tuple) would be better)

And `std::tuple` has [operators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/operator_cmp) which

> Compares lhs and rhs lexicographically, that is, compares the first elements, if they are equivalent, compares the second elements, if those are equivalent, compares the third elements, and so on.

And the above description is also the idea how to make a comparison of more than value.

Comment: OP wants length, no `repeat`

Comment: All right, I've added your code and `tuple` library to my project, but nothing happens. Like it just doesn't execute. I've read about `std::tie` for a while, but I guess I missed something.

Comment: @enjoy where did You use this code? In the ```if``` statement?

Comment: @Jarod42 I thought that ```repeat``` was the other variable to be compared. I modified the answer to suggest using ```make_tuple``` when function results have to be compared.

Comment: I would combine this answer and use it in the "Make a comparator function."

Comment: `std::forward_as_tuple` might also be used to avoid any copy.

Comment: @Jarod42 Great! Added to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a lambda to [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to do this:

```
sort(begin(array), end(array), [](const auto& lhs, const auto& rhs){ return *lhs.word < *rhs.word || *lhs.word == *rhs.word && (strlen(lhs.word) < strlen(rhs.word) || strlen(lhs.word) == strlen(rhs.word) && strcmp(lhs.word, rhs.word) < 0); });
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](https://ideone.com/9pMhzy)